# Docker compose : Cassandra not connecting to my application in same network

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

My application is dependent on Cassandra DB, so i have put all of them in a docker-compose file, now simply using plain docker as given [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-cassandra/) i'm able to run it fine locally but when i try using the same configuration in compose i keep getting the same error,

my compose file:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  myapplication:
    image: eclipse-temurin:17.0.7_7-jre
    working_dir: /root/app
    restart: on-failure
    command: sh -c "java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=docker /root/app/app.jar"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - jar:/root/app/
      - ./logs:/root/app/logs
  db:
    image: cassandra:5.0
    restart: always
    container_name: cassandra
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME: app
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
      - "9160:9160"
      - "7199:7199"
    volumes:
      - cas_data:/var/lib/cassandra
volumes:
  cas_data:
    driver: local
networks:
  default:
    name: my-application
```

and my property file is

```
spring.cassandra.schema-action=CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS
#spring.cassandra.request.timeout=10s
#spring.cassandra.connection.connect-timeout=10s
#spring.cassandra.connection.init-query-timeout=20s
#spring.cassandra.keyspace-name=app
#spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=cassandra
spring.cassandra.local-datacenter=datacenter1
```

I have tried to even hard code the contact-point but to no avail, I'm able to access the cassandra in the compose container, but my application can't seem to access it.

error:

```
Suppressed: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:9042
                Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
                        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
                        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Unknown Source)
                        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
                        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:337)
                        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
                        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776)
                        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
                        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
                        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
                        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
                        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
                        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
                        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        Caused by: io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException: null
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0()(Unknown Source)
```

what's the cause of this issue and how can i resolve this?

---

**EDIT**

on top of the previous stacktrace, i will add another one as it comes at the top of the above error

```
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=7b503e49): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException)]
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException.copy(AllNodesFailedException.java:141) ~[java-driver-core-4.15.0.jar!/:na]
```

I'm giving correct contact point as i get this in the container

```
# nc -zv cassandra 9042
Connection to cassandra (192.xxx.xxx.x) 9042 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dotnetcore console app : rabbitmq with docker Connection refused 127.0.0.1:5672](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48361367/dotnetcore-console-app-rabbitmq-with-docker-connection-refused-127-0-0-15672)

Comment: The duplicate is for a different port and service, but the solution will work if adjusted for yours.  TLDR: "Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:9042" each docker has its own localhost interface, so using 127.0.0.1 / aliases in docker containers is generally a mistake. In your case you should be connecting to `db`, the name of the container from docker-compose.

Comment: that's the point even if i do specify `db` or `cassandra` (as it was previously) it always takes `127.0.0.1` not the one i specified, I'm not understanding why?

Comment: i have edited with more information

Comment: then your configuration is incorrectly setting up the hosts.  Are you sure it's not supposed to be `contactpoints` vs `contact-points`?  Just a guess from https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#cassandra-connectors.xmlconfig

Comment: i would have agreed with you but when i run locally it works fine, without any errors

Comment: because locally cassandra is probably listening on 127.0.0.1 right?  so the default configuration works there.  I would be more interested if you could *break* it running outside docker by setting the host setting incorrectly

Comment: actually as i'm running in windows so cassandra is not running locally but by docker, (https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-cassandra/) and when i do set the contact point incorrectly it stopped working giving the same error of not reaching contact point